# WriterT or ReaderWriterStateT?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

I'm trying to apply `WriterT` to my case and faced some problem. I have the following writer according to my needs:

```
val writer: WriterT[Option, List[IO[Unit]],  Set[String]] = //
```

And this is pretty much fine. But the problem is I need to *contramap* the writer's value in some cases. In particular I have a function

```
val f: String => Set[String] = //...
```

I tried this:

```
import cats.instances.option._
writer.contramap(f)
```

But this failed with compile error:

```
Error:(26, 39) could not find implicit value for parameter F: 
        cats.Contravariant[Option]
```

I found a workaround for this using `ReaderWriterStateT[Option, Set[String], List[IO[Unit]], Unit, Unit]` and the following (`Kleisli::local` does not require `Contravariant`):

```
val rws: ReaderWriterStateT[Option, Set[String], List[IO[Unit]], Unit, Unit] = //
rws.local(f)  //compiles
```

But I think it looks weird and like a crazy workaround. Actually I need only `WriterT`'s  semantic, not reader. Can we make `WriterT` work here?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need to contramap the writer?